# match strings or values from cfg with csv file

Tags: python, xml, csv, elementtree, matching

The goal is to find matched strings between a cfg file and xml file then list all the strings that don't have a match.

What have I done so far:

- read and parse all xml files in the directory
- save the parsed elements in a csv file

From csv file (which contains the xml data), planning to match strings from csv with cfg file.

Question. Am I on the right track or is there a better way to program this with python? Thank you

example cfg:

```
**ac2d-text data** = ac2d
asfrom compressed win executable (generic) = exe
```

example xml file:

```html
<Info>
  <FileType>**Mac OS X Mach**</FileType>
  <Ext>data</Ext>
```

- **ac2d-text** data in cfg and **Mac OS X Mach** of filetype element in xml should be matched, if not it should be written as output csv

Comment: What determines a match? Which two strings inside the files do you compare to see if there is a match?

Comment: hi @jollibobert please see edited question. thanks

Comment: "Am I on the right track or is there a better way to program this with python?" It is hard to tell, since you haven't shown us any Python code.

Comment: Update the post with a **VALID** xml document.